# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - WHERE clause

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have stored the following query in a String to request my OracleDB:

```
"SELECT firstname, lastname, COUNT(kids)  
FROM test_table  
WHERE firstname in ('mario',  'peter')  
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
ORDER BY firstname, lastname;"
```

When I execute the query via my Java Application and JDBC I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
    at com.foo.test.App.main(App.java:30)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove semi-colon, here:

```
ORDER BY firstname, lastname;"
                            ^
                            |
```

Comment: Could you explain why ? When I am using the SQL Developer to request my DB I always end my queries with a ";"

Comment: JDBC is intended to execute a statement one at a time. Semicolon in SQL is used as a statement separator.
So the semicolon it is not part of statement syntax for many database including Oracle that I'm using. Some JDBC drivers will remove it automatically

Comment: Because - when you execute it "via my Java Application and JDBC", semi-colon causes an error. Something similar to dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) where a statement can't be terminated by a semi-colon.